# file selector not showing on clicking file input

Tags: angular, angular8

component html :`<input type="file" name="notImportant" (change)="handleFileInput($event)">`

component ts :`handleFileInput = e => {console.log(e);}`

[image]

this is very simple html, when i click on choose file; nothing happens, no error either.
not sure if any package is blocking default action. it was working before i started api integration.
adding before and after contents of `package.json`.

Before:

```
"dependencies": {
    "@angular/animations": "~8.2.14",
    "@angular/common": "~8.2.14",
    "@angular/compiler": "~8.2.14",
    "@angular/core": "~8.2.14",
    "@angular/forms": "^8.2.14",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "~8.2.14",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "~8.2.14",
    "@angular/router": "~8.2.14",
    "@coreui/coreui": "^2.1.16",
    "@ng-select/ng-select": "^3.7.1",
    "@ngx-translate/core": "^11.0.1",
    "bootstrap": "^4.4.1",
    "font-awesome": "^4.7.0",
    "jquery": "^3.4.1",
    "ngx-pagination": "^5.0.0",
    "rxjs": "~6.4.0",
    "tslib": "^1.10.0",
    "zone.js": "~0.9.1"
  },
```

After:

```
"dependencies": {
    "@angular/animations": "~8.2.14",
    "@angular/common": "~8.2.14",
    "@angular/compiler": "~8.2.14",
    "@angular/core": "~8.2.14",
    "@angular/forms": "^8.2.14",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "~8.2.14",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "~8.2.14",
    "@angular/router": "~8.2.14",
    "@coreui/coreui": "^2.1.16",
    "@ng-select/ng-select": "^3.7.1",
    "@ngx-translate/core": "^11.0.1",
    "@types/axios": "^0.14.0",
    "angular-bluebird": "0.0.1",
    "axios": "^0.19.2",
    "bootstrap": "^4.4.1",
    "font-awesome": "^4.7.0",
    "jquery": "^3.4.1",
    "ngx-pagination": "^5.0.0",
    "rxjs": "~6.4.0",
    "tslib": "^1.10.0",
    "zone.js": "~0.9.1"
  },
```

**UPDATE**

if i put `<input type="file" name="notImportant" (change)="handleUpload($event)">` in `app.component.html` it works.

Comment: For starters you have a mismatch in your event handler names.  handleUpload will not call handleFileInput if that is what you intended to do. In the FWIW category I used a blank project and all worked then used you dependency list with an npm update and it still worked.

Comment: even if i remove event handler, it wont show up. :( wasted whole day.

Answer (score 0):

```
**Check This**

 <button type="button" mat-button (click)="choosefile.click()">ChooseFile</button>      
 <input type="file" #choosefile name="requestfile" (change)="onFileChange($event)" accept="application/pdf, image/*">

 <span>{{filename}}</span>

  onFileChange(event){
  var file = event.target.files[0];
  this.filename= file.name;
  }
```

Comment: Thank you for answering. the issue was something else. i had put a `div` covering `router-outlet` to hide sidebar whenever user clicks outside the sidebar. that was causing this weird issue. not sure if i have to mark your answer as selected.

Answer (score 0):

The same thing happened to me. I had a sidebar like Manjunath that closed when I click outside this, is weird but I change the
`(click)="mobile && closeSide == false && closeSide = true"`

To

```
(click)="CloseSideBar()"


//ts
CloseSideBar(){
   if(this.mobile && this.closeSide == false){
      this.closeSide = true
    }
}
```

and fixed the file selector bug.